# Random password shared between services?

Tags: security, passwords, docker-compose

Consider the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: src
    environment:
       POSTGRES_USER=app
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
  [...]

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
       POSTGRES_USER=app
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
```

Now, I prefer not to check in `mysecretpassword` (even if in theory, an attacker should never have access to anything that this password would work on, nor my source code).

An approach that I experimented with is to generate the password from a starter bash script and set an enviroment variable, then substituting above:

```
       POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${MY_GENERATED_PASSWORD}
```

This works, but has the downside of me having to wrap docker-compose in custom bash scripts all the time (which I may or may not prefer to do anyway).

This has to be such a common problem, is there a better solution around? Ideally, I would have liked to have the functionality built into docker compose to generate random strings to use as passwords.

Or should I just give up and check the password? (I think this is the pragmatic approach, considering the attack surface is wide open if either of the containers gets compromised anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Top security: don't store password at all.

- run password rotation service that changes DB password every N minutes
- application (or a proxy) implement retry-on-auth-error when it hits edge case when password was already changed in DB but application still has old one

Otherwise, surely docker-compose is supposed to be a tool that builds containers, not a tool that builds your project. Have a build script that runs whatever *-compose thing is in trend this week, they will change for sure, but your build script will remain a stable user interface.

Comment: Not storing (persisting) the password at all is exactly what I want to accomplish.